# Defining CDN path for multiple files included in a bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle, bundling-and-minification

This is my first time that I want to use bundling and minification. And I found examples and explanations for almost everything but using a cdn path for a bunch of files included in a bundle. all examples that uses a cdn were like:

```
var styleSheet = new StyleBundle("~/JQMstyle", "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css").Include("~/theme/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css");
styleSheet.CdnFallbackExpression = "window.jQuery.mobile";
bundles.Add(styleSheet);
```

they just add a cdn path and include only a single file. what if I include multiple files?

- Can I just use a folder path as a cdn path and include multiple files?
- If not then what is the purpose of bundling when using a cdn path?

**Update:**

What I mean here is that I have my own CDN like cdn.mysite.com and I just want to include all files in the css folder (that all have the same cdn folder path with only different file names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a CDN(Content Delivery Network) is to have multiple places host the file so it is available geographically closer to the end user. If bundling work like what you were asking for it would be coming only from your server. When you bundle a CDN you can provide backup files/non-minified files that can be used during debugging.

Another benefit of a CDN is if the user used that CDN on a different site already it would already be cached in their browser.

Comment: but I want to bundle several css files into single file. Then how could I use a cdn?

Comment: by the way, I'm already using cdn for images, javascripts and css on my website. now that all css files are going to be one (javascripts too) I don't know how to do this having my cdn

Comment: Bundling is the process of taking multiple files and making it one. If you did this even from a CDN the file would have to made (at least in memory) from your sever. If you want to bundle multiple files from CDNs and host them on your sever you will need to download them into your project first and reference them that way. (without a CDN)

Comment: I don't know how else to say this other than it doesn't work like that.